# HPHP HipHop for PHP error "The value of HPHP_HOME does not exist"

Tags: php

I'm getting this error:
The value of HPHP_HOME does not exist

when I run cmake . under hiphop directory.

Is there a step I can do to fix this issue?

Comment: Is your wanting to run HipHop an attempt to [increase the speed of your web scraping?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446439/php-google-web-scrapper-performance-issue) Because that is very unlikely to help

Comment: @Pekka it's for internal sites as I need to use them for scrapping of my sites for development purposes and this needs to be done on a regular basis

Comment: There are much, much better ways to scrape sites on a regular basis, e.g. `wget`... Are you sure PHP is the ideal solution for this in the first place?

Comment: Anyway, maybe this helps:  http://huichen.org/en/2010/07/deploy-hphp/

Comment: Well, I thought about this too and that's why I thought using low-level language like C++ would help thus I came up with idea of Hip Hop but seems like wget could be useful aswell. I'm just open to ideas if possible. thanks

Comment: if the slowness comes from connecting and downloading, a low-level language won't help you because the libraries PHP uses are already written in a low-level language and the performance issues come from the actual process of transmitting the data through the network. Depends on what is actually causing the problems

Comment: All of your questions so far are too localized.

Answer (score -1):

You need to define HPHP_HOME environment variable.

See https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/Running-HipHop (that's actually first link found on google):

```
cd .. # into the root of the hphp checkout
export HPHP_HOME=`pwd`
export HPHP_LIB=`pwd`/bin
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure? Post output of `echo $HPHP_HOME`. If there's value, please post last 10-15 lines of cmake output.